# PYTHON - Display percent of 100 in stacked horizontal bar plot from crosstab from matplotlib in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked

This is my piece of code.
Everything is okay except it display 0% which is wrong.
Here is my piece of code. What is wrong?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax= pd.crosstab(df4['State'], df4['Status_new']).apply(lambda r: r/r.sum()*100, axis=1)
ax_1 = ax.plot.barh(figsize=(10,10),stacked=True, rot=0)
display(ax)
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 1.0), title="Subject")

plt.xlabel('Status')
plt.ylabel('State')

for rec in ax_1.patches:
    height = rec.get_height()
    ax_1.text(rec.get_x() + rec.get_width() / 2, 
              rec.get_y() + height / 2,
              "{:.0f}%".format(height),
              ha='center', 
              va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

And here is result. I need to show actual percentage.

[image: current figure with 0%]

Comment: Can you post a portion of your dataframe?

Comment: could you please right correct syntax please. It doesn't work when I replace the line               "{:.0f}%".format(height), with "{:.0f}%".format(rec.get_width())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a horizontal `barh()`, the `text()` string should be `width` instead of `height`:

```py
"{:.0f}%".format(rec.get_width()),
```